# No 'decodeIfPresent' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '[ModelMemberSubCategory]!'

Tags: ios, swift, model, codable

I have two custom struct models using `Codable`. One is `ModelMemberCategory` & other one is `ModelMemberSubCategory` which is child of `ModelMemberCategory`. Here is the code snippet:

**ModelMemberCategory**

```
struct ModelMemberCategory: Encodable {

    var catId : Int!
    var catName : String!
    var fields : [ModelMemberSubCategory]!

    //For Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case catId = "cat_id"
        case catName = "cat_name"
        case fields = "fields"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        catId = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .catId)
        catName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .catName)
        fields = try values.decodeIfPresent([ModelMemberSubCategory].self, forKey: .fields) // This line throws error on Xcode 9.4.1 but not on Xcode 9.2
    } 
}
```

**ModelMemberSubCategory**

```
struct ModelMemberSubCategory: Encodable{

    var fieldCategory : String!
    var fieldCode : String!
    var fieldDatatype : String!
    var fieldId : Int!
    var fieldName : String!
    var fieldType : String!
    var fieldValue : String!
    var fieldValuetype : String!
    var fieldVisible : String!


    //Codable
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fieldCategory = "field_category"
        case fieldCode = "field_code"
        case fieldDatatype = "field_datatype"
        case fieldId = "field_id"
        case fieldName = "field_name"
        case fieldValue = "field_value"
        case fieldValuetype = "field_valuetype"
        case fieldVisible = "field_visible"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        fieldCategory = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldCategory)
        fieldCode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldCode)
        fieldDatatype = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldDatatype)
        fieldId = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .fieldId)
        fieldName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldName)
        fieldValue = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldValue)
        fieldValuetype = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldValuetype)
        fieldVisible = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fieldVisible)
    }
}
```

Now the problem is its building in Xcode 9.2 but not in Xcode 9.4.1. While I try to build using 9.4.1 I'm getting error like this:

> No 'decodeIfPresent' candidates produce the expected contextual result
>   type '[ModelMemberSubCategory]!'

on

`fields = try values.decodeIfPresent([ModelMemberSubCategory].self, forKey: .fields)` in `ModelMemberCategory`

I don't know what Apple changed in Xcode 9.4.1 version but can anyone help me to overcome this error?

Comment: Question  - why are your properties implicitly unwrapped vars? `var catId : Int!` should be `let  catId: Int` I've seen a lot of this recently… who is spreading this terrible idea?

Comment: Also - you can remove your CodingKeys… just set your `JSONDecoder().stringDecodingStrategy`

Comment: And… unless you're doing some custom init (you're not), there's no need to implement  `init(from decoder: Decoder)`

Comment: @AshleyMills Thanks for the suggestion. And about the _implicitly unwrapped vars_ I got this from a online codable model generator [site](http://www.jsoncafe.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Decodable` instead of `Encodable`. `Decodable` is needed to represent the external entity to your type

Changing `Encodable` to `Decodable` fixes the error.

The code builds in XCode 9.2 because in Swift 4.0(<4.1), the compiler is not checking whether your structs conform to Decodable or not. 
This got fixed in Swift 4.1(XCode 9.3+), by making use of [Conditional conformance.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md)
You can read more about it [here.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/50/whats-new-in-swift-4-1)

On a side note, in `ModelMemberSubCategory`, `fieldType` is missing. I hope its intentional.
Also, `decodeIfPresent` returns `Optional` values but all your instance variables are non-optionals. If you think some variables can be nil, you should make them Optional, so that you can handle nil values in your code in a better way.

Comment: Thanks and yes, its intentional. But I wonder how this code gets executed on Xcode 9.2.

Comment: @Poles: In Xcode 9.2(< Swift 4.1), complier was not checking whether struct conforms to Decodable protocol or not. It got fixed in Swift 4.1. I have edited the answer.